# bash is not executed 'at -f foo.sh' command, even with #!/bin/bash shebang

Tags: linux, bash, at-job

I'm using the 'at' command in order to create 3 directories, just a dumb bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
do
mkdir dir$i
done
```

Everything is ok if I execute that script directly on terminal, but when I use 'at' command as follows:

```
at -f g.sh 18:06
```

It only creates one directory named `dir{1..3}`, taking interval not as an interval but as a list with one element `{1..3}`. According to this I think my mistake is using bash script due to `at` executes commands using /bin/sh but I'm not sure. 
Please tell me if I'm right and I would appreciate some alternative to my code since even it is useless I'm curious to know what's wrong with at and bash.

Comment: Yes, `at` executes the commands from file `g.sh` at the given time. It will read each commands from this file. It's like doing `sh g.sh`. Instead try `at 18:06 <<< "/full/path/to/g.sh"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#!` line only affects what happens when you run a script as a program (e.g. using it as a command in the shell). When you use `at`, it's not being run as a program, it's simply used as the standard input to `/bin/sh`, so the shebang has no effect.

You could do:

```
echo './g.sh' | at 18:06
```